# Rapid-Fire AJAX Requests in Rails Leads to Data Overwrite on Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, apache, fastcgi

#### The Problem

I've run into a problem after moving a rails 3.2.8 app from WEBrick to Apache with FCGI.

The app includes a game written in javascript that sends a lot of AJAX requests in order to update game statistics on the server.

This works fine using WEBrick, but now that I have switched to Apache if I make several rapid-fire updates to the same record they seem to be over writing one another. For instance if I have 15 ajax calls that get sent at roughly the same time to update the 'points' value by 5 points each request, the total score will not add up at 75, where I want it, but will instead be some varying lower number ranging between 5 and 45.

I believe this is due to apache being able to handle multiple requests at one time.

#### What I Think is Happening

- The StatisticsController recieves a request to add points.
- The controller opens a copy of the Statistic record from the database.
- The model adds 5 to the currently recorded number of points.

  - ***Before the record is saved*** the controller recieves another request to add points.
  - It opens the record which still holds the old points total.
  - It adds 5 points to the old total.
- The first request's record saves.

  - The second request's record saves.

*Point total has only incremented by 5 instead of 10.*

#### What I've Tried

I've tried various methods of "locking" the record to prevent it being opened while in the process of writing using ActiveRecord callbacks, but so far without success.

I've tried several web searches, but I have yet to come up with the magic keywords to give me the answers I am seeking.

#### The Question

Is there a way to prevent these requests from overwriting each other, or is there some other way I can handle this on the server? (I know I could code the javascript statistics to either wait before sending another request or to merge the requests, but it seems to me like the server should be able to handle as many requests as I can throw at it.)

It's entirely possible that I am way off on my approach here as well and would be happy for any suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working using a [transaction block](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) in concert with [pessimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html).

The code now looks like the following:

```
  # GET /statistics/request.json
  def request
    # Begin a transaction
    Statistic.transaction do

      stat = Statistic.find(params[:id], lock: true) # Lock the record until we're done with the transaction.

      stat.total_points += 5

      stat.save!

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: stat }
      end
    end
  end
```

You must also be sure to use a database engine that supports locking, in my case MySQL running InnoDB.

Special thanks to this article for showing me the light: [Pessimistic locking doesn't seem to work with mysql?](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/365151)